# PHP using Laravel 5.2 and Carbon not adding months correctly

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have created a method to calculate a loan application amortization schedule. I am using Carbon to add a month for each time the user has to make payments on their loan and here is snippet of my code:

```
 public function amoritization($amount,$interest_rate,$repaid_months,$start_date)
{
    $beginning_balance = $amount;
    $interest = $interest_rate/100/12;
    $payback = $repaid_months;
    $x = pow(1 + $interest,$payback);
    $monthly_payment = ($beginning_balance*$x*$interest)/($x-1);

    $payment_date = new Carbon($start_date) 


    $info = (object)[]; //convert empty array to an object
    $amoritization = [];
    $count = 0;
    while($payback > 0){
        $total_interest = $interest * $beginning_balance; //interest
        $principal_payment = $monthly_payment - $total_interest; //principal
        $ending_balance = $beginning_balance - $principal_payment; //ending balance

        $info->beginning_balance = (float)$beginning_balance;
        $info->total_interest = $total_interest;
        $info->payment = $monthly_payment;
        $info->principal_payment = $principal_payment;
        $info->ending_balance = $ending_balance;
        $info->payment_date  = $payment_date->addMonths($count++);

        array_push($amoritization,$info);
        $beginning_balance = $ending_balance;
        $info = (object)[];
        $payback--;
    }

    return $amoritization;
}
```

This method is invoked in my controller like this:

```
  return $this->calculation->amoritization($data['amount'],$data['interest_rate'],$data['loan_term'],$data['start_date']);
```

Here is the issue, say for example the $start_date variable stored this value 2016-04-14 10:34:56 and the $payback variable has the value of 6. In the while loop statement I have the $info object adds a property of payment_date that stores the added month:

```
 $info->payment_date  = $payment_date->addMonths($count++);
```

When the while loop statement loops one time the value I should get is 2016-05-14. However, this what I got back from the response:

```
payment_date :{date: "2016-10-14 10:34:56.247000", timezone_type: 2, timezone: "Z"}
```

Also, When I do this in the loop:

```
return    $info->payment_date;
```

I get back the value 2016-05-14. What could be the cause of this? Thanks in advance for your help,

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
$info->payment_date  = $payment_date->addMonths(1); //or just $payment_date->addMonth();
```

Let's say: `$start_date = '2016-04-14'`;

Your problem is that `$count++` is 1 in the first iteration and adds **1 month**.

`$payment_date` is now `'2016-05-14'`

In the second iteration `$count` equals `2` now and adds **2 months**.

`$payment_date` is now `'2016-07-14'`

In the third iteration `$count` equals `3` now and adds **3 months**.

`$payment_date` is now `'2016-10-14'`

When you do `return` inside the loop it's stopped after its first iteration.

Comment: I tried this $info->payment_date  = $payment_date->addMonths(1);, but still getting the same date which is 2016-10-14 for each payment_date property from the array of objects

Answer (score 0):

I have face the same problem.

Apparently there is a bug. You cannot use addMonths() to a date which is at the end of the month like 30th april or 31st may.

I'm still not sure why but if you use addMonths() with date like 1st of February, it will add up nicely and correctly.

Basically you have to adjust the date to earlier date before you use addMonths();

This bug was making me crazy.

Comment: To avoid those problems (adding months to month that starts with 30th and 31st) Carbon offers methods `addMonthsNoOverflow()` and `subMonthsNoOverflow()`